broken events when adding change background image on calendar
this calendar will be the death of me.
the events now dissappear when i alter the background div to change with the month name.  i've narrowed it down to the line between the called images and the image style code: literally the }; line. i have tried changing everything anf it will not have both the events and background image show at that same time.
   November: "url('assets/images/pgs/month11.png')",
  December: "url('assets/images/pgs/month12.png')"
}; <-- THIS IS THE ISSUE RIGHT HERE, THIS LINE -->

calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage = colors[month];

can someone please help me either have static events that i have to code for the calendar or fix it so the events and the background show up at the same time?


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },

    initialDate: '2024-01-12',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    nowIndicator: true,

    weekNumbers: true,
    weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2024-01-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2024-01-07',
        end: '2024-01-10'
      },
      {
        groupId: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-01-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-01-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2024-01-11',
        end: '2024-01-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2024-01-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2024-01-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2024-01-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2024-01-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2024-01-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2024-01-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2024-01-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2024-01-28'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
  });

  calendar.render();

  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");

  //select the div which the style changes will be applied to
  const calendarBackgroundNode = document.getElementById("background");


  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    let monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
    let month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
    changeBackground(month);
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);

  // Function to change background
  function changeBackground(month) {
    const colors = {
      January: "url('assets/images/pgs/month01.png')",
      February: "url('assets/images/pgs/month02.png')",
      March: "url('assets/images/pgs/month03.png')",
      April: "url('assets/images/pgs/month04.png')",
      May: "url('assets/images/pgs/month05.png')",
      June: "url('assets/images/pgs/month06.png')",
      July: "url('assets/images/pgs/month07.png')",
      August: "url('assets/images/pgs/month08.png')",
      September: "url('assets/images/pgs/month09.png')",
      October: "url('assets/images/pgs/month10.png')",
      November: "url('assets/images/pgs/month11.png')",
      December: "url('assets/images/pgs/month12.png')"
    };

    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage = colors[month];
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundPosition = "right";

  }
  changeBackground(new Date().toLocaleString('default', {
    month: 'long'
  }));
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar/index.global.min.js'></script>
<!-- div bg container for calendar -->
<div id="background" class="bgcontainer">
  <div id='calendar'><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <!-- end of div bg container for calendar -->




I don't know if it's just a snippet of your actual full code or not but in the example HTML above you're missing a closing div tag

it's all of the code except the external js. the missing div tag isn't doing anything to fix the code either :(

@ADyson i can't see any changes in the code sadly. the calendar script is broken in your edit but even correcting it on my end and running it, i wasn't able to make it work :(

@MachaNeko I'm not trying to answer your question with that edit - the answer is not part of the question!! I was just making it so the script would actually run - which it does now, without basic errors crashing it. So it's a far better demonstration of your issue. After all what's the point of a "runnable code snippet" which doesn't actually run, and doesn't show what the problem is? So that's all I was doing - the point of editing someone's question is to improve the question, not fix the problem. I'm working on an actual answer.

There are a couple of issues with your current script:

You're initialising the calendar twice - the first time with events in it, and then a second time without any events. Since you attached both calendar instances to the same HTML element, the second one directly overwrites the first, which is why your events don't show up. It's unclear why you added the second initialisation - it's not needed as far as I can see, so you can simply remove it.

Your calendar is initialised to a fixed date - 2024-01-12, but your initial call to changeBackground (when the calendar is first loaded) uses today's date instead. So that means that - apart from when "today" happens to be in January - you'll get the wrong background when you first load the calendar. You can correct that by putting the initial date value into a variable which is passed both to fullcalendar and to populate the Date object in the first changeBackground call.


I've corrected both of these in the runnable demo script below. I also merged your two DOMContentLoaded blocks into one - while this has no real functional impact, having two blocks of code which do the exact same job is just clutter.
N.B. Since I don't have your background colour image files for the demonstration, I've added a temporary command: onsole.log(calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage);, just to prove that the code is selecting the correct background image when the month is changed on the calendar.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var initDate = '2024-01-12';

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },

    initialDate: initDate,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    nowIndicator: true,

    weekNumbers: true,
    weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2024-01-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2024-01-07',
        end: '2024-01-10'
      },
      {
        groupId: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-01-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2024-01-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2024-01-11',
        end: '2024-01-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2024-01-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2024-01-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2024-01-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2024-01-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2024-01-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2024-01-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2024-01-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2024-01-28'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");

  //select the div which the style changes will be applied to
  const calendarBackgroundNode = document.getElementById("background");


  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    let monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
    let month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
    changeBackground(month);
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);

  // Function to change background
  function changeBackground(month) {
    const colors = {
      January: "url('assets/images/pgs/month01.png')",
      February: "url('assets/images/pgs/month02.png')",
      March: "url('assets/images/pgs/month03.png')",
      April: "url('assets/images/pgs/month04.png')",
      May: "url('assets/images/pgs/month05.png')",
      June: "url('assets/images/pgs/month06.png')",
      July: "url('assets/images/pgs/month07.png')",
      August: "url('assets/images/pgs/month08.png')",
      September: "url('assets/images/pgs/month09.png')",
      October: "url('assets/images/pgs/month10.png')",
      November: "url('assets/images/pgs/month11.png')",
      December: "url('assets/images/pgs/month12.png')"
    };

    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage = colors[month];
    console.log(calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundImage);
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    calendarBackgroundNode.style.backgroundPosition = "right";

  }

changeBackground(new Date(initDate).toLocaleString('default', {
    month: 'long'
  }));
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar/index.global.min.js'></script>
<!-- div bg container for calendar -->
<div id="background" class="bgcontainer">
  <div id='calendar'><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <!-- end of div bg container for calendar -->
</div>



